# Nesting queries

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

My query from the attached schema is asking me to look for the same location of where the people who tested positive went and were in the same people as the untested people. (Untested means the people not there in the testing table.

[image: Schema]

```
--find the same locations of where the positive people and the untested people went  

select checkin.LocID, checkin.PersonID 
from checkin join testing on checkin.personid = testing.personid 
where results = 'Positive'
and  (select CheckIn.PersonID  
from checkin join testing on checkin.PersonID = testing.PersonID where CheckIn.PersonID
not in (select testing.PersonID from testing));
```

In my view the query is stating the following

To select a location and person from joining the checking and testing table and the result is positive and to select a person from the check in table who is not there in the testing table.

Since the answer I am getting is zero and I know manually there are people. What am I doing wrong?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What results do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the people tested 'Positive' with this query:

```
select personid from testing where results = 'Positive'
```

and the untested people with:

```
select p.personid 
from person p left join testing t 
on t.personid = p.personid
where t.testingid is null
```

You must join to each of these queries a copy of `checkin` and these copies joined together:

```
select l.*
from (select personid from testing where results = 'Positive') p
inner join checkin cp on cp.personid = p.personid
inner join checkin cu on cu.lid = cp.lid
inner join (
  select p.personid 
  from person p left join testing t 
  on t.personid = p.personid
  where t.testingid is null
) pu on pu.personid = cu.personid
inner join location l on l.locationid = cu.lid
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked and gave me the location. If i had to find the personid also, I am presuming I would have to put ` checkin.personid `next to select?

Comment: Another question is why do you put the 1.* and not the (*) alone. What does the 1 signify?

Comment: `l`  (not 1) is the alias of the table `location`. If you also want persons you can add `p.*` for the infected persons or `pu.*` for the untested.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want are the *positive* people who are at a location where there is also someone who is not tested, you might consider:

```
select ch.LocID,
       group_concat(case when t.results = 'positive' then ch.PersonID end) as positive_persons
from checkin ch left join
     testing t
     on ch.personid = t.personid 
group by ch.LocId
having sum(case when t.results = 'positive' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       count(*) <> count(t.personid);  -- at least one person not tested
```

With this structure, you can get the untested people using:

```
group_concat(case when t.personid is null then ch.personid)
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes I was looking for the people who are positive and were at the same place as the people who were untested.

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes (missing exists, independent subquery in exists). I believe that this should do the work

```
select ch1.LocID, ch1.PersonID 
from checkin ch1
join testing t1 on ch1.personid = t1.personid 
where results = 'Positive'
and exists (
    select 1
    from checkin ch2    
    where ch1.LocID = ch2.LocID and ch2.PersonID not in (
        select testing.PersonID 
        from testing
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you. But it gave me the results of the person who is positive only and I was looking for the person who are positive and were at the same place as people who were untested. Thank you for your help.